# Oracle XPATH, extract values from simple xml

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

very simple xml, table has 2 rows with column named Description (XMLType)

```
row 1: <a>aaa</a>
row 2: <a>opis</a>
```

i would like to extract rows where text contains "opis", others can be empty.

This is how I tried to do that:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(DESCRIPTION, '*//A[contains(text(),"opis")]') FROM DATAS D;
```

It doesn't work...

this is how my table looks like:

CREATE TABLE DATAS
(
  ID NUMBER(3) NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION XMLTYPE NOT NULL
);

I noticed, I switched off brain for a while, this is what I want to achieve:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM DATAS D WHERE EXTRACTVALUE(DESCRIPTION, '*//A[contains(text(),"opis")]') IS NOT NULL;
```

but this query doesn't work.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not an error message or a useful description of what is wrong. Perhaps you could be a bit more specific.

Comment: It doesn't output error, query just returns nothing (no rows selected) so I assume XPath is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Tag names are case-sensitive, and you don't need the `*` root, so your first query should be:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(DESCRIPTION, '//a[contains(text(),"opis")]') FROM DATAS D;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/541e0/5).

And the second should be:

```
SELECT DESCRIPTION
FROM DATAS D
WHERE EXTRACTVALUE(DESCRIPTION, '//a[contains(text(),"opis")]')
  IS NOT NULL;
```

(I'm pretty sure there are other, possibly better, ways to do this, but this isn't really my area...)